# Warning from signalr.exe references not being able to load Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild, signalr

Just had this start creeping into my builds of an asp.net mvc 5 project I run internally. I have a afterbuild msbuild step that generates the signalr hub code at compile time:

```
<Exec Command="$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils.2.2.0\tools\signalr.exe ghp /o:$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Scripts\signalR.hubs.js" WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" />
```

Recently I started getting warnings from Visual Studio 2015 when I compile, stating that EXEC

> could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Likewise,  I get a duplicate warning referencing the same assembly but with x86 inserted for amd64 in the name.

I haven't run into this type of warning previously, anyone seen this specific issue or know a good place for me to dig further into this?

Comment: I have the same problem. But I also get `Could not load file or assembly 'node.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.`